# NextAuth generating [next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR] when using Facebook Provider

Tags: facebook, next.js13, next-auth

I'm trying to sign in `nextauth 4.24.5` with facebook (google is working fine)

Client:

```
signIn('facebook')
```

...[nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import FacebookProvider from 'next-auth/providers/facebook'


export default NextAuth({
    session:{ strategy:'jwt' },
    providers:[
        FacebookProvider({
            clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_SECRET,
        }),
    ]
})
```

Error:
[image]

[image]

I tried modifying:

```
FacebookProvider({
   clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
   clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_SECRET,
   idToken: true
}),
```

But the error changed to:

[image]

These are my facebook settings;
[image]
[image]

I tried putting in http://localhost:3000/ and http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/facebook in `VAlid O Auth Redirect URLs` but got the following message `http://localhost redirects are automatically allowed while in development mode only and do not need to be added here`

Anyone has any idea to solve this problem?

`"next": "13.5.4",  "next-auth": "^4.24.5",`